# Term for removing/replacing line-breaks

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming

I'm looking for a good term for removing line-breaks from a piece of text and replacing them with a special line-break marker. (Like how, when quoting poetry, we use "/" to represent a break; though my case is in a software context, the goal being amenability to line-oriented tools like `grep`.)

Since various RFCs use the term "linear white space" (LWSP) to refer to within-line whitespace (namely tabs and spaces), I'm considering the term "linearize"; but I'm afraid that it might be too opaque, since there are so many other kinds of linearization. I want to use this term as the name of a function/method/procedure/subroutine that performs this transformation, so it should ideally stand on its own and convey at least a rough idea of what the transformation is.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's called "reformatting".

Comment: @HotLicks: Thanks for your suggestion. This is definitely an example of reformatting, but I don't think it's at all guessable what `reformat(msg)` would mean . . . :-/

Comment: You could use `makeGrepFriendly()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest *flatten*, as it conveys a visual image of what the transformation will achieve.

Comment: @DogLover The OP requested a term, I provided a term I thought would be serviceable for his/her purpose. I certainly answered the question, though whether my answer is useful to the OP may be a different story.

Comment: Absolutely. My decision was influenced by the StackExchange guidelines (i.e. answers are expected to be definitive, contain references, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, I think that the term *flatten* has developed a fairly specific meaning in programming: we "flatten" hierarchical structures (such as nested lists or nested loops) by converting them into non-hierarchical structures, or at least by reducing the number of levels in the hierarchy. (For example, `[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]` would "flatten" to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.) So something like `flatten(msg)` would probably be confusing.

Comment: Having thought about this further, I think "flatten" can work as the verb, it just needs a little bit more detail. I think I'll go with `flattenToSingleLine` (or something along those lines). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX, the term for this operation has long been referred to as ***joining***, from the `ed`/`sed`/`vi`/`emacs` command that appends lines end to end.

> `(.,.+1)j`
>   **Joins** the addressed lines. The addressed lines are deleted from the buffer and replaced by a single line containing their joined text. The current address is set to the resultant line. 
>   <sub>[GNU `ed` Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)</sub>

---

> In Vim you can **join** two lines together, which means that the line break
>   between them is deleted.  The "`J`" command does this.
>   <sub>[Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.4)</sub>

---

> `M-^`
>   Merge the previous and the current line (`delete-indentation`). This “**joins**” the two lines cleanly, by replacing any indentation at the front of the current line, together with the line boundary, with a single space.
>   <sub>[GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Indentation)</sub>

(The old binding for <kbd>`M-^`</kbd> used to be `join-line`, but that command has been turned into an alias for `delete-indentation` in newer versions of GNU Emacs.)

Answer (score 0):

In computer terms you could refer to the line break as the *End of Line sequence* (EOL) or line delimiter. So you want to operate globally (meaning all occurrences in the file) on the EOL by either:

- find and replace
- substitution
- transliteration

The last term is use in the Perl language http://codewalkers.com/c/a/Programming-Basics/The-Transliteration-Operator-in-Perl/

So as a term, something like *line break substitution* could work

While the file will now appear flat when viewed in a text editor, I wouldn't use the tewm *flatten or linearize*. A file is just a sequence of bytes, so it is really linear to begin with. We jut denote EOL as the symbol to add line breaks.

Comment: Thanks; so I guess your suggestion is `replaceLineBreaks(msg)`?